# Streaming is much slower than Downloading

Tags: download, vlc-media-player, streaming, upload

I have a media server at home that I use to distribute media to players in the house. I have recently set up a VPN so that I can access my media remotely, but I have noticed something odd.

If I move a 45 minute video file from my media server to my laptop over the VPN, it takes 22 (ish) minutes, however, if I play the same video file (in VLC through a VPN accessed over a Windows Share, via VPN), it constantly (every 30-60 seconds) stutters and pauses and has to buffer.

I have tested the latency, and there is no downtime during a copy (copying at 300kbps constantly_ but at no point does the speed drop below 270kbps.

So, why does streaming playback do this when it could be copied faster than full playback?

p.s. When I want to play files remotely, I do copy them, this is more of a "but whhhyyyy?" question

Comment: You listed the speed of copy, what was the speed during streaming?  How much more "upload" or requests for data going in the other direction exists with the streaming vrses the copying? What was the connection method? Does your connection method have ways to adjust the duplexing? (even if that may mean purposfully testing 1/2 duplex)  What is the networking adapter, and did you check out any options it has for jumbo packets (which may not help) and the buffering that itself uses to move stuff around? (including reducing that bufferrring to reduce latency at the costs of speed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bandwidth is different than latency. For example, If I put a bunch of hard drives on a plane, I can move hundred of terabytes anywhere in the world in just a few hours. But the time to the first byte is also measured in hours. If I copied the data over the Internet, the time to first byte may be milliseconds, but it would take more than a few hours to move all the data.

VLC begins to play the file and it copies a few second worth of video, then stops downloading and begins playing, when that buffer is starting to run low, it goes back to the network to get more data, but if it takes longer to get that data then their is time left in the buffer, it stop. hence the term buffering. There should be a setting in VLC to increase the buffer (cache) size for high latency playback.

Comment: "VLC begins to play the file and it copies a few second worth of video, then stops downloading and begins playing". Why does it stop downloading and then play the video ? Can't VLC play the video in the buffer while simultaneously download more to fill up the buffer ? It seems pretty obvious that this will make things better with a very small increase in CPU usage. Right ? :)

Comment: The buffer is limited, usually because the buffer is stored in memory. Yes, it can play while downloading, and it does. But with high latency high bandwidth connections, the buffer fills fast and drains fast, But there is a small delay before it starts filling again. Think of it like this You're at a red  light (the buffer is full). Once it turns green, (the buffer hit a low water mark) you are not instantly going 60mpg. So the red light caused your average speed to drop.

Answer (score -1):

Downloading it to your computer is easier, its instant and nothing can stop it when playing the file. Streaming is why its slow, because it goes over wifi, which is a wireless signal. So streaming isn't that great. Your better off downloading the files to watch than to stream.

Comment: among many questions I have about this, who said WiFi..